# running python def and cipher text

Tags: python, encryption

So I have this function which is suppose to de-crypt a cipher text but I do not know how to run this function, I barely use python any help would be must appreciated.

```
def decrypt1(ctext, key):
    if key % 4 == 0:
        perm = [4, 1, 3, 6, 7, 5, 2, 0]
    elif key % 4 == 1:
        perm = [2, 4, 0, 5, 7, 6, 3, 1]
    elif key % 4 == 2:
        perm = [1, 7, 0, 2, 6, 5, 3, 4]
    else:
        perm = [5, 4, 1, 7, 0, 2, 3, 6]
    rev_perm = [perm.index(i) for i in range(len(perm))]
    ptext = ""
    for j in range(0, len(ctext), 8):
        block = ctext[j: j+8]
        ptext += ''.join(block[p] for p in rev_perm)
    return ptext
```

Here is the ciphertext

> ehn Aotrf irtmeot m  enoiaoig sl sgnn iinis  prga hmwen rinta fs sse
>   eelo v aesnothmte phssoot oa  ftof erg i-terasea lghta  s ep-oifotraht
>   n tt w aacomt eeks;h e enthsp  saisa,eaasbl ihd n tsehssi t  grapins
>   gliiintoFe m. rray m ptn  tIdoosip  raeoft i, raeytm hr sdo oenek itli
>   cu. t Shli nasais  agisn,dcathe uodwn y ahldil rovydl aihcme isite.if
>   Y ie  nthrargcinon n oemed neh vetofs i, rhtemwal l afensip  oetootr
>   lrmoatu;is b f  atiset f rulomainde o e agthwB etvs.udiIy  b nouio
>   cslae dr l ehhtesti n igsnh oayure st r aID a sy.oupo nt toylral usdgi
>   oo ll wnhaosps  hi; eehlavtae eegrttr brpa ,dhaein tudtn p seeeh lstr
>   orpa ra ;nbodi f  ortb sdi aanibs usem  estoeht dtwi ets iasr
>   gmhaontev  ewasehfso t saaie,  b  dtisaoyi  f uotu pt o tr geaao o
>   ladnw ogyuranao gn d krhbeatel  eax,oynrad usdga oo opelr sibOdee.
>   sudv re erue:masep ao ndroio prtnses i btllnti a .si hng

Comment: to run do `decrypt1("you text", "your key")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refs:

```
ctext = "your ciphertext"
result = decrypt1(ctext, key)
print(result)
```

Please make your ciphertext as your first argument, and the key as your second argument to your function decrypt1 according to your actual situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = '''ehn Aotrf irtmeot m  enoiaoig sl sgnn iinis  prga hmwen rinta fs sse
eelo v aesnothmte phssoot oa  ftof erg i-terasea lghta  s ep-oifotraht
n tt w aacomt eeks;h e enthsp  saisa,eaasbl ihd n tsehssi t  grapins
gliiintoFe m. rray m ptn  tIdoosip  raeoft i, raeytm hr sdo oenek itli
cu. t Shli nasais  agisn,dcathe uodwn y ahldil rovydl aihcme isite.if
Y ie  nthrargcinon n oemed neh vetofs i, rhtemwal l afensip  oetootr
lrmoatu;is b f  atiset f rulomainde o e agthwB etvs.udiIy  b nouio
cslae dr l ehhtesti n igsnh oayure st r aID a sy.oupo nt toylral usdgi
oo ll wnhaosps  hi; eehlavtae eegrttr brpa ,dhaein tudtn p seeeh lstr
orpa ra ;nbodi f  ortb sdi aanibs usem  estoeht dtwi ets iasr
gmhaontev  ewasehfso t saaie,  b  dtisaoyi  f uotu pt o tr geaao o
ladnw ogyuranao gn d krhbeatel  eax,oynrad usdga oo opelr sibOdee.
sudv re erue:masep ao ndroio prtnses i btllnti a .si hng
'''

print(decrypt1(data, 3))
```